# Performing a function after another

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulty getting another function to work after one has just completed. The first half of my code works, but the function afterwards doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

The HTML

```
<div id="feature">
    <div id="open"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#feature {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:450px;
}
#open {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}
```

The jQuery

```
$('#open').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: 50
    }, {
        duration: 'slow'
    }).css('overflow', 'visible'),
    function () {
        $('#open').animate({
            height: 200
        }, {
            duration: 'slow'
        })
    };
    // Animation complete.
});
```

A JS Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/C8fA7/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ **complete**: A function to call once the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function needs to be an argument to `animate`, but you've put it after `css`, long after you've finished the call to `animate`. Try this instead:

```
$(this).animate({
    height: 50
}, {
    duration: 'slow'
}, function () {
    $('#open').animate({
        height: 200
    }, {
        duration: 'slow'
    })
}).css('overflow', 'visible');
```

This becomes clearer if we make explicit the chaining:

```
var temp = $(this);
temp = temp.animate({ height: 50 }, { duration: 'slow' });
temp = temp.css('overflow', 'visible');
```

At that point, you're just left with this stray function:

```
function () {
    $('#open').animate({ height: 200 }, { duration: 'slow' });
}
```

There's no syntax error there, but it does nothing since it's never called.

Also, your comment `// Animation complete` indicates you might not realize animations are asynchronous. When you finish the `animate` statement, the animation has been started, but it has not yet finished. Your callback function will be called when the animation is complete; the statements following the `animate` call will not wait.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easiest way:

```
// Do stuff (Pt. 1)
setTimeout(function() {
    // Do more stuff (Pt. 2)
    setTimeout(function() {
        //Do even more stuff (Pt. 3)...
    }, 0);
}, 0);
```

Not sure if ES/JS intended setTimeout to be used this way, but even though a duration of 0ms is specified, the function still honors a when/then, or when/done 'sequence' that waits for the first function (or actions) to complete before proceeding. Subsequent functions are known as 'callbacks', though I think this is a poor word choice - they don't call back to anything and proceed forward!